# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores que me da una respuesta?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una tabla ya hecha que me muestra todo bien pero necesito sumar el "valor" en una variable aparte como un "total".

Aqui lo que tengo hecho.

```
returnedData["facturas"].forEach(function(facturas){
            let valor = 0;

            valor = facturas["valor"];
            total = total;
            total = valor + total;
            console.log(total);

            $("#facturacion-data").append("<tr><td>" + facturas["creation_date"] + "</td><td>" + (facturas["id_socio"] == "0" ? "NA" : facturas["socio"]["nombres"]) + "</td><td>" + (facturas["id_socio"] == "0" ? facturas["apellido"] : facturas["socio"]["apellidos"]) + "</td><td>$" + facturas["valor"] + "</td></tr>");

        });
```

Y me muestra los resultados como muestro aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero sumar todos los "valor" que hayan en un total.

Adjunto tambien una captura de la respuesta del servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto tambien lo que me da la consola asi como esta mi codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que te aparece en consola?

Comment: Hola, gracias, he agregado el resultado por consola a mi pregunta :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tienes que convertir el valor the texto a entero asi:

```
returnedData["facturas"].forEach(function(facturas){
        let valor = 0;

        valor = parseInt(facturas["valor"]);
        total = total;
        total = valor + total;
        console.log(total);

        $("#facturacion-data").append("<tr><td>" + facturas["creation_date"] + "</td><td>" + (facturas["id_socio"] == "0" ? "NA" : facturas["socio"]["nombres"]) + "</td><td>" + (facturas["id_socio"] == "0" ? facturas["apellido"] : facturas["socio"]["apellidos"]) + "</td><td>$" + facturas["valor"] + "</td></tr>");

    });
```

Comment: Vaya ciertamente solo me faltaba el parseInt, use fue parseFloat ya que me da decimales, muchisimas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// informacion de ejemplo para la respuesta
const returnedData = {
  facturas : [
    {
      valor : 10
    },
    {
      valor : 20
    },
    {
      valor : 30
    }
  ]
}

const total = returnedData["facturas"].reduce((acumulado, item) => acumulado += Number(item.valor), 0)

console.log(total)
```